# How do you use gcloud's multiple cpu to speed up your program with Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

In order to get more speed on my mac using Python I use the fork feature.  My mac has 4 cores and I noticed that if I use 4 forks, my program speeds up by 3.7 times.  Any additional forks do not make the program faster.  I'm not even certain if successful forking relies on the number of cores or not, in fact I know very little about what is really going on, I just know that it works. I realize that on gcloud the vCPU = 5 does not necessarily mean there are 5 cores, but I was hoping that more CPUs would somehow help the forking process go faster.  In any case, I put the following python program on a 16 vCPU gcloud computer and I saw no increase in speed.  The following program just counts up to 250,000,000.  Using 4 forks on my mac it takes 16 seconds, but using 16 forks on the 16 vCPU gcloud it takes 18 seconds.

```
import functools, time, os

p = print


def print_intervals(number, interval, fork=None, total=0, print=True):
    if number > 0 and number % interval == 0 and number >= interval:
        if total:
            per = int((number / total) * 100)
            number = f"{number} - {per}%"

        if fork == None:
            p(number)
        else:
            p(f"fork {fork}")
            p(number)
        return

def timer(func):
    """Print the runtime of the decorated function"""

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        run_time = round(run_time, 2)
        print(f"Finished {func.__name__!r} in {run_time} secs")
        return value

    return wrapper_timer

@timer
def temp1(**kwargs):
    start = kwargs['start']
    stop = kwargs['stop']
    fork_num = kwargs['fork_num']
    for x in range(start, stop):
        print_intervals(x, 10_000_000)
        z = x + 1
    p(f'done fork {fork_num}')


def divide_range(divisions: int, total: int, idx: int):
    sec = total // divisions
    start = idx * sec
    if total % divisions != 0 and idx == divisions:
        stop = total
    else:
        stop = start + sec
    return start, stop


def main_fork(func, total, **kwargs):
    forks = 16
    fake = kwargs.get("fake")
    for i in range(forks):
        start1, stop1 = 0, 0
        if total != -1:
            start1, stop1 = divide_range(forks, total, i)
            p(f'fork num {i} {start1} {stop1}')
        if not fake:
            newpid = os.fork()

        kwargs['start'] = start1
        kwargs['stop'] = stop1
        kwargs['fork_num'] = i
        if fake and i > 0:
            pass
        elif fake:
            func(**kwargs)
        elif newpid == 0:
            child(func, **kwargs)
    return


def child(func, **kwargs):
    func(**kwargs)
    os._exit(0)


main_fork(temp1, 250_000_000, **{})
```

Comment: Just looking at elapsed time is a very crude measure. Profile your application, and see for yourself what's happening.

Comment: Obviously, if I'm using 4 times more cores, with no reduction in speed and I'm using the exact same program then I'm not taking advantage of the additional cores.  Further, I get a 3.7 times increase in speed when I use the forking process.  It follows that when I increase the number of forks to 16, then there is something about forks that I'm not understanding.

Comment: Yes, I read your question. My advice still stands. https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: All of my programs speed up by that ratio when I use forking and none of them gain additional speed when the number of forks increase beyond 4. Further, the program just counts up to 250 million.  Profiling is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: Let me ask you this: do you know how to speed up a program if a computer has 16 CPU rather than 1?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again and this time it worked.  A 16 vCPU N1 machine sped up the program by a factor of 5.  I'm not sure what I did different but the only thing I can think is that I was actually using the 1 vCPU computer when I thought I was using the 16 vCPU computer.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this, however, you may want to see the built-in `multiprocessing` library.

Python was created before CPUs with multiple cores were around, so it runs on one single thread - no matter how many `threading.Thread` instances you run.

When using the `multiprocessing` library, you're effectively running Python *x* amount of times. For example, you'd be running a different Python instance on each core of the CPU to speed things up by a marginable amount.